How to configure logwatch to send mail
This on an Intel iMac running Sequoia
I have logwatch running on a Raspberry Pi which works just fine. However, I'm having trouble getting logwatch on a Mac to send the results via email.
On both the Mac and the Pi I'm using MSMTP as an SMTP client. They are configured identically with gmail as the relay host.
On the Pi I use the following in the config file:
mailer = "/usr/sbin/sendmail -t"

If I use the same on the Mac, it appears to work with no error message, but the mail never gets delivered. There are no error messages in the msmtp log.
I know logwatch is working because if I use:
Sellotape:conf mnewman$ sudo logwatch --output stdout

I get:
 ################### Logwatch 7.11 (07/22/24) ####################
        Processing Initiated: Wed Dec 18 12:43:29 2024
        Date Range Processed: yesterday
                              ( 2024-Dec-17 )
                              Period is day.
        Detail Level of Output: 5
        Type of Output/Format: stdout / text
        Logfiles for Host: Sellotape.local
 ##################################################################
<snip>

Sending mail from the Mac on the command line works just fine:
Sellotape:~ mnewman$ mail me@mac.com
Subject: hi mac
done
.
EOT

Sellotape:~ mnewman$ cat .msmtp.log
Dec 18 12:50:18 host=smtp.gmail.com tls=on auth=on user=me 
from=me@gmail.com recipients=me@mac.com mailsize=178 
smtpstatus=250 smtpmsg='250 2.0.0 OK  1734501018 98e67ed59e1d1-
2f2ed644980sm487477a91.26 - gsmtp' exitcode=EX_OK


What have I done wrong to keep logwatch from sending results via email?

Are you sure mail sends via msmtp and not sendmail?

did you try to change this setting :
mailer = "/usr/sbin/sendmail -t"

to this one :
mailer = "/path/of/msmtp -t -i"

where /path/of/msmtp is obtained with the command :
which msmtp


Yes, that worked. Can you explain why? On the Raspberry Pi I use: mailer = "/usr/sbin/sendmail -t" which works just fine. I also have msmtp installed on the Pi.

After posting the above I did a littler more research on msmtp and in the documentation I find the phrase: "tell your MUA to call msmtp". But, nowhere is it explained how to do this. I'm baffled.

yes, I think the macOS version of postfix that is called from sendmail, does not know anything about msmtp the way it's configured.

I saw there's a conf file that may help you to set a global setting for the mta (mail transport agent). It's the file /etc/mail.rc see https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/640296/configuring-mail-command-to-use-msmtp... I think you could try there to put "set mta=/opt/local/bin/msmtp" at the end of the file

Thanks. I tried doing that, but after doing so I was unable to send mail using just: mail me@mac.com. So, that means that all the scripts I have using "mail" to send mail will be broken. So, I'll just leave mailer = "/path/of/msmtp -t -I" in the logwatch configuration.

It's safer to keep things like that because changing the mta, even if you achieve doing this, may complicate things with Apple's Mail application for example especially if you use several mail accounts.
